# Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2' for key 1 in symfony doctrine using form widgets

Tags: php, forms, symfony1, doctrine

I can't update the form usinf formwidgets, I'm using doctrine and symfony 1.4.

Here is my code

```
protected function processFormUpdate(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form){
    $form->bind($request->getParameter('tblallusers'),$request->
                 getFiles($form->getName()));
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $logement = $form->save();

        }
        else {
            $this->getUser()->setFlash('error', 'error');
        }
}


public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
{
echo $id = $this->getRequestParameter('id');
$object = Doctrine_Core::getTable("Tblallusers")->find($id);
$this->form = new TblallusersForm($object);
}

public function executeUpdate(sfWebRequest $request)
{
echo $id = $this->getRequestParameter('id');
  $object = Doctrine_Core::getTable("Tblallusers")->find($id);
  $this->form = new TblallusersForm($object);
  $this->processFormUpdate($request, $this->form);
}
```

The above code throws an error like

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2' for key 1

Please help me out of this......

Comment: @arasu to format code just select it and click the `{}` button or press `Ctrl + K`. It will automatically indent it four spaces and get formatted.

Comment: Where exactly is the error thrown? Also, show us your form's code.

Comment: The error is thrown when the save method is called in processForm

Comment: We need to see your form's code, as @Maerlyn said.

Comment: Seems like that one of your fields should have unique values. SHow us your form/schema.

Comment: When the id i.e $this->getRequestParameter('id'); is empty it will throw this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id should be grater than zero and should be unique